Importing unordered timestamp data into Timeseries DB (Druid/InfluxDB/Postgres)
I have billions of records in a file which are unordered timestamp data, means not in sequence order.(Ex the file has records in order mar-apr, then apr-june, then feb-mar, july-aug, jan-feb)
If i import this file into timeseries db, will it import successfully and ordered in DB?
Or it should be always in sequence order?

InfluxDB can import your unordered data without problems. You don't need to sort it first, but sorting might make the import faster. Once imported, InfluxDB will automatically store the data in time order. Just remember to check your retention policies, as very old data points might not be kept if they're outside the set time range.
